# CodeIgniter Angular File Folder Dynamic URL Route

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter

I have an application with my views in CI folder.

`domain.com/apps/view/user/xxx.php`

I put Angular on

`domain.com/apps/assets/js/app.js`

`domain.com/apps/assets/js/controllers.js`

Currently I am using a static URL to load my view in this application.
I use CI Controller for database processing and Angular Controller and Route to display and process the info in the interface.

I face issues when a backup domain is added.

app.js

```
 angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])

 .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {         
if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
}
if (window.StatusBar) {
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
}
  });
})

  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$location) {
  $stateProvider

  .state('app', {
url: "/app",
abstract: true,
templateUrl: "http://m.domain.com/_aps4497/views/user/menu.php",
controller: 'AppCtrl'
 })

   .state('app.main', {
url: "/main",
views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl:  "http://m.domain.com/_aps4497/views/user/main.php"
  }
}
 })

  .state('app.message', {
url: "/message",
views: {
  'menuContent': {
       templateUrl: "http://m.domain.com/_aps4497/views/user/message.php"
  }
}
 })



  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/main');
});
```

I tried :

```
  .state('app.message', {
url: "/message",
views: {
  'menuContent': {
       templateUrl: "http://"+$location.host()+"/_aps4497/views/user/message.php"
  }
}
 })
```

error : it is retrieved the same .

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$location) {
     $stateProvider

   .state('app', {
url: "/app",
abstract: true,
templateUrl: "http://"+$location.host()+"/_aps4497/views/user/menu.php",
controller: 'AppCtrl'
   })

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=starter&p1=$location%20is%20not%20defined <br>
```

controller.js

```
 angular.module('starter.controllers', ['pascalprecht.translate'])

.factory('UserService', function($http) {
var data;   
      return{
          getData: function($http) {
                    return $http.get("http://m.domain.com/user/getUserInfo").
                    success(function(response) {
                     /// console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                      userData=response.data;
                            return userData;

                   }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                     // log error
                    });
          }
    }
})
```

1. How do we set the route and location to be dynamic (multiple domain)?
2. Whats the best practice for the folder system on Angular + CI?
   if i want to put all my views in the partial folder, where should I put the partial folder to be possibly accessed by Angular controller and app.s?

Please help!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You seems to have not injected the `$location` before using it..

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$location)
```

and the use it:

```
templateUrl: "http://"+$location.host()+"/_aps4497/views/user/message.php"
```

Comment: hi I forgot to update the question. i have injected `$location` but it still has the same error.